# What is the solution to this matrix optimization problem $A^* = \text{argmin}_{A} \sum_{i=1}^{r-1}|Ax_i-x_{i+1}|^2$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-analysis

The motivation for asking this question, is that if the vectors represent word embeddings in natural language processing, then the matrix, should represent a document consisting of a sequence of words / word embeddings.

I have a sequence of vectors over the real numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_r$ and I am searching a matrix $A$ which will minimize the following error:

What is the solution to this matrix optimization problem $A^* = \text{argmin}_{A} \sum_{i=1}^{r-1}|Ax_i-x_{i+1}|^2$?

Here $|.|$ denotes the Euclidean norm of the vector $Ax_i - x_{i+1}$.

Thanks for your help.

(My calculation in matrix analysis are a bit rusty and I have computed the following "solution":

$$A = \frac{1}{2} ( \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} x_{i+1}x_i^T) ( \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} x_{i}x_i^T)^{-1}$$

but  this solution migh be wrong.)

Comment: I recommend you show how you obtained your supposed solution; then it is more easily verified/mistakes pointed out

Comment: @FShrike: I tried to compute the derivative with respect to the matrix, set it to $0$ and solve for the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrices
$\mathbf{R}_1=
\left[
\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_{r-1}
\right]$
and
$\mathbf{R}_2=
\left[
\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_{r}
\right]$

The objective function writes
$\phi(\mathbf{A})
= \| \mathbf{A} \mathbf{R}_1 - \mathbf{R}_2 \|^2_F
$
The closed form solution is
$$
\mathbf{A}
=
\mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1^T
\left(
\mathbf{R}_1 \mathbf{R}_1^T
\right)^{-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Very nice! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this separable by rows of $A$? Because the squared norm is just a sum of squares.  Assume $A$ is $n\times n$.  Row $j$ of $A$ is given by $R_j$ (an $n-$vector).  Then your objective is:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} \Big( R_j \cdot x_i -x_{i+1,j}\Big)^2.$$
So you can solve for each best row vector $R_j$ on its own.  Say using linear regression.

Comment: (+1) Thanks. I implemented it the way you describe it. Works very well.